# AngularJS Save Data POST , Syntax Error: Token 'danger' is unexpected

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

While posting my model to service to save data , im getting following error , not able to figure out why

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'danger' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 10 of the expression [{'alert-'danger'': true, 'alert-dismissable': closeable}] starting at [danger'': true, 'alert-dismissable': closeable}].
```

this is how im calling SAVE for my model

```
ContractsService.ContractHeader.save(this.contractHeaderModel,
            angular.bind(this, function (data, headers) {
                debugger;
                icAlertService.successtoast("Contract saved successfully."); //ASM NLS
                //this.goBack();

            }),
        function (error) {

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your server is returning is illegal json:

```
[{'alert-'danger'': true, 'alert-dismissable': closeable}]
```

Just looking at this you can tell somethings off as there are single quotes in certain places that don't make sense. Perhaps you mean this:

```
[{'alert-\'danger\'': true, 'alert-dismissable': closeable}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for input, what I see is when im posting data ,my service always gets data as null , any idea ?
 
this is how I post data
save: { method: 'POST' }

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding something like this before I pass JSON object to POST

{'expectedobjectname':objectToPost}

this is how Service was expecting data to receive.